# Is my implementation of exclusiveMinimum property correct?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am using `JsonSchema 2.6.0` for the validation of form data for my python program.

I am trying to implement `exclusiveMinimum` but when I post to the form it accepts 0 as a valid value, but it shouldn't.

```
        from jsonschema import Draft3Validator

        orderValidationSchema = {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "total_amount": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRef",
                    "required": "true",
                    "exclusiveMinimum": 0
                },
                "payable_amount": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRef",
                    "required": "true",
                    "exclusiveMinimum": 0
                },
            },
            "definitions": {
                "floatRef": {
                    "type": "number",
                },
            }
        }
```

After going through few git issues and other links I tried it in the way shown below but still it didn't work.

```
        from jsonschema import Draft3Validator

        orderValidationSchema = {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "total_amount": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRef",
                    "required": "true",
                    "minimum": 0,
                    "exclusiveMinimum": "true"
                },
                "payable_amount": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRef",
                    "required": "true",
                    "minimum": 0,
                    "exclusiveMinimum": "true"
                },
            },
            "definitions": {
                "floatRef": {
                    "type": "number",
                },
            }
        }
```

Please do let me know if I am making any mistakes.

I am using `Draft3Validator` just in case there is any issue active related to it.

Below is the json that is passed to this schema.

```
    {
         "total_amount" : 100000,
         "payable_amount" : 10000
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide your JSON instance you are trying to validate?

Comment: One problem is you are using `Draft3Validator` but your schema identifies as a draft-4 JSON Schema.

Comment: I have updated the question with the JSON that I am passing. As for the other question, `Draft3validator` working perfectly in another schema that I have created where I am referencing draft-4 JSON Schema.

Comment: Great! I have a solution for you. Posting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few issues with your schema.
First, `exclusiveMinimum` must be a boolean, not a string.
Second, `required` needs to be an the object level, and not the property level, as the schema is specified as a draft-4 schema. You should use Draft4Validator if possible.

Third, `$ref`. This keyword, all the way to draft-7, replaces the content of the whole object, meaning other key words in that object are ignored.
The solution is to wrap the two schemas you want to apply to the instance property in an `allOf`. I've demonstrated this with the following schema, which seems to do what you're asking.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "total_amount": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRefMTZ"
    },
    "payable_amount": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRefMTZ"
    }
  },
  "required": ["total_amount", "payable_amount"],
  "definitions": {
    "floatRef": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "floatRefMTZ": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/floatRef"
        },
        {
          "minimum": 0,
          "exclusiveMinimum": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

("MTZ" is just shorthand for More Than Zero. You can call it whatever you like.)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Needed a bit of tweaking though, since draft3validators doesn't support lists. Marking this as the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, if you can't use draft-4, then you'll have to modify the use of the `required` keyword. We strongly suggest using the newest draft you can. That implementation supports 3, 4, and 6. Is there any reason you're unable to move from draft-3?

Comment: Its being used with other services within our application and there are couple of dependencies that we don't want to address right now. But we'll eventually move on draft-4 in next couple of months.

Comment: Ah OK. If you can, I'd move to draft-6, as that's closer to the final spec than 4. Support for 7 with that library is on its way too!